# Why chewing a battery increases its power?

Tags: electricity, everyday-life, batteries

I know almost nothing about physics. Last night my TV remote was not working. I chewed the batteries and woh! It still had power left.

How does chewing a battery increases its power? I think it's a 12V pair of batteries.

Comment: total guess, cos I have never thought much about chewing batteries :) is that your saliva is slightly acidic and this has some effect.

Comment: Wait, a battery wasn't working so you tried to *eat it*? Did something get lost in translation?

Comment: @AcidJazz Trust me, it's not saliva.I have used this trick many times.But just curious why it happens.I know may be it increases the discharging mechanism by crushing lead sulphate?

Comment: Is there any video of someone doing that? It might help to visuzalize *how* you chew it.

Comment: total guess(v2), as i think you imply, you are increasing the density by crushing it and bringing the conducting components closer together.  I have to admit, I know lead acid car battery makeup ok, not sure about domestic ones.  Does it it still work when you crush it in a vice or mangle it with a hammer

Comment: See http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/2429/

Comment: @AcidJazz It's working now.Once I over did it and it leaked the next day.

Comment: just to finish off, i had a quick google and saw one reference to the same effect on radio controlled car batteries that were put in a vice and he claimed they lasted longer, but it's hard to find the right keywords to narrow it down

Comment: Be very careful.  If it's a lithium ion battery, chewing it might cause metal parts in the battery's interior to contact each other and short-circuit, which could cause a runaway thermal event.

Comment: though some of the ideas sound odd to me. maybe there is a good question here - there are a few possibilities. it could be: heat, cleaning the terminals, compressing the battery, shaking the battery etc.

Comment: in any case, don't chew any more batteries. if there is a beneficial effect, you can probably replicate it in a safe way

Comment: @innisfree yeah I saw the link you referred. Good to know others have also experienced it.But the correct reason is still under covers.

Comment: The potential of a battery is caused by a chemical reaction. If there is an effect I would expect the explanation to be in chemistry, not physics.

Comment: Batteries will recover some power if you simply stop using them for a few minutes.  During operation, reaction products tend to pile up at the electrodes which slows the forward reactions.  If the battery is not used for a few minutes, the chemical products diffuse back into the bulk, and power output is temporarily improved.  It is likely that the chewing provided the time for this to happen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the chemistry of chewing a battery to make it work again

Comment: @Jimself Is there any way it can be migrated to correct forum ?

Comment: @joeyrohan flag it with a custom message asking a moderator to migrate it

Comment: Batteries are an interesting technology. The specialty manufacturer in town hires people from chemistry, physics and engineering backgrounds for their R&D positions because there is no undergraduate major that provides the skillset they need; so they get people with part of it and train them the rest of the way in house.

Comment: There is a flag requesting migration to "somewhere useful", but I don't know where that would be.

Comment: @dmckee I guess  http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ is a good place.Cannot update the flag.

Comment: The Chemistry mods have ask that it not be migrated.

Comment: @dmckee This is definitely a Chemistry question! On what bases the have rejected the migration ?